# Will every goldfish never stop growing?

Tags: fish, goldfish, biology, growing

I'm confused whether goldfish will never stop growing or not, how much will its genetics affect its size?

I want to buy a high quality goldfish, not a bad one.

Comment: Related: [Why don't fish grow to their full size in a small tank?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/27893/12501)

Answer (score 1):

Koi maximum about 4 ft , some have been documented to be about 100 years old ( in Japan).But I have seen some older koi limited to about 2 ft ; so genetics must be a factor . Koi and goldfish are closely related. In my small pond ( roughly 800 gallons ) the biggest koi has been about 32". Their size is greatly limited by the size of the water body . So if one has a 55 gal. aquarium , my guess is 12" would be about the maximum size goldfish. You need not worry about a goldfish becoming "too big". This is anecdotal but I have seen at least 50 ponds, public and private with maximum dimensions well over 100 ft.

Comment: One koi pond I have seen is at the Sumitomo museum in Kyoto Japan ;  The ponds / garden were private at the time. .Pardon me but I do not get to mention that very often.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanako_(fish) http://www.hanakokoi.com/