# Why is my pleco growing extremely fast after being introduced to large tank?

Tags: aquarium, fish, pleco

**Hi!**
I got my pleco when it was still quite small, and it quickly outgrew its 10-gallon tank (I know 10g is too small but I was on a budget) and I just now moved all my fish(pleco included) to a 36 gallon tank.
I soon noticed my pleco is much more active, and then I noticed how BIG it is! It was perhaps 7-8 inches long on the 10g but it is now probably about 9-10 inches long!
Does anyone know why it grew so fast? It's only been a week and I'm starting to get worried.

Thanks.

Comment: a pleco will grow to about 50 cm in good conditions same as goldfish and koi.but a pleco will adapt its growth to the size of your tank so it should grow a lot slower from about now and onwards.

Comment: Related question and possibly the answer to your question: https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/27893/12501

Comment: @trondhansen it will not adapt, it will poison itself in a small tank and so grow slower... Nothing to wish the fish I assume ;)